# How can I work with 2 streams where stream two is depending on stream one?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, stream

I have 2 streams

```
  Stream<List<GroupModel>> groupStream() {
    final CollectionReference groupCollection = fireStore.collection('groups');

    return groupCollection
        .where('members.${user.id}', isEqualTo: true)
        .snapshots()
        .map((snapshot) => snapshot.documents.map((document) => GroupModel.fromFirestore(document)).toList());
  }

  Stream<List<GroupSubscriptionModel>> groupSubscriptionsStream(List<GroupModel> groups) {
    final chunks = chunkSizeCollection(groups, 10);
    List<Stream<List<GroupSubscriptionModel>>> streams = List<Stream<List<GroupSubscriptionModel>>>();
    chunks.forEach((chunck) => streams.add(fireStore
        .collection('users/${userID}/userGroupSubscriptions')
        .where(FieldPath.documentId, whereIn: chunck)
        .snapshots()
        .map((snapshot) =>
            snapshot.documents.map((document) => GroupSubscriptionModel.fromFirestore(document)).toList())));
    return ZipStream(streams, (value) => value.last);
  }
```

What I want is get all the groups and then from the user get the subscriptions which basically say if the users is subscribed to the group or not. Then in my UI I toggle a icon based on if the user is subscribed or not.

My problem is that my `groupSubscriptionsStream` is depending on the id's from the groups to get the corresponding document. Because I can't just stream all the document's in a collection. If I could I didn't have any problem.

I am using bloc's with provider to provide my stream controllers to my widget. But my `StreamSubscriptionsBloc` needs a `List<GroupModel>` in order to add the stream to it's controller

```
class GroupSubscriptionsBloc{

  final StreamController<List<GroupSubscriptionModel>> _controller = StreamController<List<GroupSubscriptionModel>>();
  Stream<List<GroupSubscriptionModel>> get stream => _controller.stream;

  GroupSubscriptionsBloc(DatabaseService database, List<GroupModel> groups)
  {
    _controller.addStream(database.groupSubscriptionsStream(groups));
  }

  void dispose(){
    _controller.close();
  }
}
```

So in the widget I have a static method that provides the two bloc's to the widget

```
  static Widget create(BuildContext context) {
    final database = Provider.of<DatabaseService>(context);
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        Provider(
          create: (_) => GroupBloc(database),
          dispose: (BuildContext context, GroupBloc bloc) => bloc.dispose(),
        ),
        Provider(
          create: (_) => GroupSubscriptionsBloc(database, null),
          dispose: (BuildContext context, GroupSubscriptionsBloc bloc) => bloc.dispose(),
        ),
      ],
      child: TheGroupOverviewPage(),
    );
  }
```

But as you can see I currently pass null to the subscriptions bloc because I do not have the groups. So I cannot add the stream to he controller.

But I do want to use both blocs in the `TheGroupOverviewPage` widget, because it wouldn't make sense to do it in a different widget.

So the question is how do I get that `List<GroupModel>`?

The thing is, I wouldn't even need two streams if I could somehow combine the two streams and map them to my `GroupModel` so that I toggle isSubscribed to true.

```
class GroupModel
{
  final String _id;
  final String _displayName;
  final Map<String, bool> _members;
  final Map<String, bool> _admins;
  bool isSubscribed = false;

  String get id => _id;
  String get displayName => _displayName;
  Map<String, bool> get members => _members;
  Map<String, bool> get admins => _admins;

  GroupModel._internal(this._id, this._displayName, this._members, this._admins);

  factory GroupModel.fromFirestore(DocumentSnapshot document)
  {
    return GroupModel._internal(
      document.documentID ?? '',
      document['displayName'] ?? '',
      document['members'] != null ? Map.from(document['members']) :  Map<String,bool>(),
      document['admins'] != null ? Map.from(document['admins']) : Map<String,bool>(),
    );
  }
}
```

I know you can combine streams, but in this case the second stream is depending on the first stream. So is this even an option? It would make the most sense because it would output the `List<GroupModel>` where isSubscribed is being set by the second stream. And I can keep everything group group related within one stream.

This is how I currently have to build the streams in `TheGroupOverview` widget

```
    body: StreamBuilder(
      initialData: List<GroupModel>(),
      stream: groupBloc.groupStream,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<GroupModel>> groupsSnapshot) {
        return ConditionalWidget(
          condition: groupsSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active,
          widgetTrue: StreamBuilder(
            initialData: List<GroupSubscriptionModel>(),
            stream: groupSubscriptionsBloc.stream,
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<GroupSubscriptionModel>> subscriptionSnapshot) {

              groupsSnapshot.data?.forEach((group) => group.isSubscribed =
                  subscriptionSnapshot.data?.any((subscription) => subscription.belongsTo(group)));

              return ConditionalWidget(
                condition: subscriptionSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active,
                widgetTrue: Builder(
                  builder: (BuildContext context) {
                    return GroupList(
                      groupsSnapshot.data,
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 25.0, left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
                      onNotificationIconTap: _onGroupNotificationIconTap,
                    );
                  },
                ),
                widgetFalse: PlatformCircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            },
          ),
          widgetFalse: PlatformCircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      },
    ),
```

**Edit - WIP**

```
    return groupCollection
        .where('members.${user.id}', isEqualTo: true)
        .snapshots()
        .flatMap((groups) => _groupSubscriptionsStream(groups) , //here should merging happen?));
  }

  Stream<QuerySnapshot> _groupSubscriptionsStream(QuerySnapshot groups) {
    final chunks = chunkSizeCollection(groups.documents.map((group) => group.documentID).toList(), 10);
    List<Stream<QuerySnapshot>> streams = List<Stream<QuerySnapshot>>();
    chunks.forEach((chunck) => streams.add(fireStore
        .collection(APIRoutes.userSubscriptions(user.id))
        .where(FieldPath.documentId, whereIn: chunck)
        .snapshots()));
    return ZipStream(streams, (value) => value.last);
```

Comment: check https://pub.dev/documentation/stream_transform/latest/stream_transform/Switch/switchMap.html / https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/SwitchMapExtension/switchMap.html / https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/FlatMapExtension/flatMap.html

Comment: So the flatmap can map both stream, do I need the switchmap then? I don't really understand what the switchmap does tbh. Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: Aah I think I understand, I use the switchmap on the group stream and then use the flat map at the end right?

Comment: the docs say: *"The switchMap operator is similar to the flatMap and concatMap methods, but it only emits items from the most recently created Stream."* - i think the best way to understand them is to use them on some test fake streams

Comment: run this code: `Stream.periodic(Duration(seconds: 3), (i) {
  print('master stream emitted ${10 * i}');
  return 10 * i;
})
.take(5)
.flatMap((i) => Stream.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 900), (ii) => '$i + $ii').take(10))
.listen(print)
.onDone(() => print('the end'));` and see the output to the end, now to see the difference replace `flatMap` with 1) `switchMap` 2) `asyncExpand` - all of those methods take a callback function where the current item of the "parent" stream is passed - `.flatMap((i) => ...`

Comment: and? does the sample code i posted explain the difference between those 3 methods?

Comment: I'm testing it right now.

Comment: So swichMap let's both streams proceed at their own pace, asyncExpand does them in order so stream 1 first then stream 2 and waits untill second stream is finished. And flat map I still don't really understand.

Comment: flatMap mixes everything up

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213229/discussion-between-mike-ottink-and-pskink).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing my firestore document so I could have a query like this

```
    return _groupSubscriptionsStream().switchMap((subscriptions) => groupCollection
        .where('members.${user.id}', isEqualTo: true)
        .snapshots()
        .map((snapshot) => snapshot.documents
            .map((document) => GroupModel.fromFirestore(document).checkSubscriptions(subscriptions))));
  }

  Stream<List<GroupSubscriptionModel>> _groupSubscriptionsStream() {
    return fireStore
        .collection(APIRoutes.userSubscriptions(user.id))
        .where('isSubscribed', isEqualTo: true)
        .snapshots()
        .map((snapshot) =>
            snapshot.documents.map((document) => GroupSubscriptionModel.fromFirestore(document)).toList());
  }
```

So I now have a isSubscribed field that is always true for the query. This does work great tho.